# Export to CSV in stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I have a stored procedure that creates a temp table and has tons of data. I have tried both of the following. I can do it manually with the export utility or results to file settings, but I would like to embed the code in my stored procedure so I can schedule the batch job and forget it. Also I do not want to us SSIS for many reasons.

Popular solution I have found are :

```
bcp "select * from WHSE.Customer" queryout ExcelTest.csv -t, -c -S . -d Server1 -T

SQLCMD -S . -d Server1 -Q “"select * from WHSE.Customer sp” -s “,” -o “d:\result.csv
```

In the BCP it get an error on BCP, if I added an `EXECUTE` in front I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

The same goes with the `SQLCMD` except error on `SQLCMD` or `-S` depending on if I use the `Execute` command.

This seems like it should be simple and I have found TONS of answers, but none actually work. It seems like it should be the most basic thing in the world, `SELECT * INTO MYFILE.CSV FROM MYTABLE` essentially.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'. and Incorrect syntax near 'S'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing "Incorrect syntax near queryout". That is a T-SQL error message. You are ,as you said, running this from within a stored procedure. Both BCP and SQLCMD are command line utilities, meaning you will have to run them from a command (DOS) prompt.

There is a way to execute directly from SQL, but you will have to use: `xp_cmdshell` Here is a good article on how to use it:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/

This was written for SQL Server 2005 but should work on 2008 as well.

Comment: Thanks Joreon, I am sure this would work since now I am getting all the errors listed in the link. To bad my DBA won't give me access to that command :( back to ssis